# How to order category by numerical order with text in cell

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I want to arrange my C column by numerical order, however the cells themselves have text in something like:

> "503 in Kitchen & Home",

I want it to detect the number but ignore the string.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the number to another column using [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en), and then sort the range by that column. For example, suppose this is your C column:

```
+-----------------------+
| 503 in Kitchen & Home |
| 85.5 in Bed & Bath    |
| -263 in debt          |
| 633.26 in something   |
| 543 in Outdoors       |
+-----------------------+
```

Enter in column D the formula

```
=VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(C1,"[0-9.-]+"))
```

(first row shown). Here `REGEXEXTRACT` extracts the first group of characters that consists only of digits, decimal dot, and minus sign. (If you don't have negative or fractional numbers, you don't need - and .) Then the `VALUE` command converts to numeric format.

Now you can select both columns C and D and sort the range by the D column. (Or sort the whole spreadsheet by the D column, if desired.)

```
+-----------------------+--------+
| -263 in debt          | -263   |
| 85.5 in Bed & Bath    | 85.5   |
| 503 in Kitchen & Home | 503    |
| 543 in Outdoors       | 543    |
| 633.26 in something   | 633.26 |
+-----------------------+--------+
```